How to delete margin between figure and subplot in matplotlib
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
fig.patch.set_facecolor('#87ceeb')
ax.set_axis_off()

ax.set_xlim(minx, maxx)
ax.set_ylim(miny, maxy)

gdf.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='#dcdcdd', edgecolor='#a5abae')
plt.show()

With this code i build this visualization:

I tried many options like
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, top=1, bottom=0)

And
ax.set_position([0, 0, 1, 1])

etc. But all of them don't work
How can I delete a small margin between figure and visualization made by  gdf.plot() ?

Maybe gdf.plot(..., clip_on=False) works for you? Note that you didn't provide reproducible test data, you even didn't mention the type of data in gdf.

You have a bunch of options. The simple/quickest one is to turn off the clip-on :
gdf.plot(ax=ax, facecolor="#dcdcdd", edgecolor="#a5abae", clip_on=False)

Or using an overlayed box :
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
ax.set(xlim=(minx, maxx), ylim=(miny, maxy))
ax.set_axis_off()

from shapely import box
gpd.GeoSeries([box(*tb)]).plot(ax=ax, fc="#87ceeb")
gdf.plot(ax=ax, facecolor="#dcdcdd", edgecolor="#a5abae")

Or with ax.patch instead of fig.patch :
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))

ax.patch.set_facecolor("#87ceeb")
ax.set(xticks=[], yticks=[], xlim=(minx, maxx), ylim=(miny, maxy))
ax.spines[list(ax.spines)].set_visible(False)

gdf.plot(ax=ax, facecolor="#dcdcdd", edgecolor="#a5abae")


Used input :
import geopandas as gpd

url = "https://naciscdn.org/naturalearth/110m/cultural/110m_cultural.zip"

gdf = gpd.read_file(url, layer="ne_110m_admin_0_countries")
gdf.to_crs(gdf.estimate_utm_crs(), inplace=True)

tb = gdf.query("ADMIN == 'Ukraine'").total_bounds
minx, miny, maxx, maxy = tb

